Matlab exportgraphics with uitable?
I have a uitable in a figure that I am trying to save as a pdf using exportgraphics.  I
believe I need to use exportgraphics because I need to append many figures into a single pdf.  Saveas can successfully create the pdf, but it lacks the option to append to an existing file. Saveas could work if there's a way to programmatically stitch 500+ pdf files together.
My figure contains 3 axes objects, 1 annontation and the uitable.  The figure and uitable are created like this:
T = array2table(data);
T.Properties.VariableNames = labels;
... lines to create the plot data ...
fh = figure;
fh.PaperType = "uslegal";
fh.PaperOrientation = "landscape";
fh.PaperUnits = "normalized";
ut = uitable(fh, Data=T{:,:}, ColumnName=T.Properties.VariableNames);
... many lines of formatting and plotting
exportgraphics(fh, 'test.pdf', Append=true)

The result is

Warning: UI components will not be included in the output.

And a pdf which contains the graphics and annotation, but no uitable.  How can I properly create a multi-paged pdf file of figures containing uitables

You have a few options here. As you've seen, exportgraphics cannot deal with uitable. This doc page summarises the different export options.
To proceed, I would suggest either

Use a command-line tool to concatenate the PDFs after creating them with saveas. See for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3378/modifying-pdf-files

A truly hacky solution would be to use saveas to export a PNG or similar, and the read that back in to use exportgraphics in Append=true mode.



I found that the uitable can be replaced with an axes and one text object per entry.  Generating the figure is still in the same time and with this approach and exportgraphics works fine.  As my figures increased the time to append increased up exponentially.  So in the end, appending with exportgraphics was much worse when compared to ghostscript.
